# Why I cannot use my GMP library in Linux

Tags: c, linux, gmp

I was writing some codes in linux using c. When tried to compiled, I got this response:

```
/tmp/ccW8mQDx.o: In function `main':
server.c:(.text+0x3e): undefined reference to `__gmpz_set_str'
server.c:(.text+0x5a): undefined reference to `__gmpz_set_str'
```

In fact, all the functions of gmp that I used couldn't be found.

Seems there are some problem with the gmp.

Could anyone please tell me how to solve it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show your build & link commands?  I guess you're probably not linking with whatever library contains that symbol.

Comment: I just use gcc server.c -o server... what else should I add?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `undefined reference` errors appear when you forgot to **link** your application with the library, GMP in this case. Read in the documentation of GMP the name of the library to link and use the `-l` compiler switch to link it.

Have you tried `-lgmp` ?

If that doesn't work you can look for the `libgmp.a` library:

```
cd /usr
find . -name libgmp.a -print
```

Comment: if that doesn't work, also add `-L/path/to/directory/containing/libgimp.so` which adds to the Library search path

Answer (score 0):

Add -l option ,when you  compile the code. It will add the library files.